# Eslint reporting eslintrc configuration problems for dependency configs

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am getting a deprecation warning when running the following lint command

```
eslint src/js/**/*.js src/js/**/*.jsx webpack.config.js --quiet
```

Warning:

> DeprecationWarning: [eslint] The 'ecmaFeatures' config file property is deprecated, and has no effect. (found in /Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react.js

This seems like it is complaining about a file listed within the `eslint-config-airbnb` under `react-a11y.js` and `react.js`. Those files do indeed include the top level configuration

```
ecmaFeatures: {
  jsx: true
}
```

which appears to be incorrect: [github issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8726), [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options). However, it seems ([docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories)) that `node_modules` should be ignored by eslint, and anyway just to be explicit, I've added the following to my *.eslintignore*

```
node_modules/**/*.*
node_modules
```

Why am I getting a warning for an issue located within node_modules? The only thing I can think is that the ignore list doesn't include configurations for eslint itself, but that seems pretty far fetched that it would potentially warning me about every out-of-date or misconfiguration of each eslintrc file in node_modules?

In case it is relevant, my *.eslintrc.json*

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2016,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier", "react"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "no-param-reassign": 0
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

#### Edit:

Upgrading to `eslint-config-airbnb@latest` (where [it looks the top-level `ecmaFeatures` problem has been resolved](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react.js#L6)) causes what look like more severe errors:

> ```
> /Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react.js:
>   Configuration for rule "react/jsx-boolean-value" is invalid:
>   Value "never,[object Object]" should NOT have more than 1 items.
>
> Referenced from: /Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb/index.js
> Referenced from: /Users/me/Documents/my-project/.eslintrc.json
> Error: /Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react.js:
>   Configuration for rule "react/jsx-boolean-value" is invalid:
>   Value "never,[object Object]" should NOT have more than 1 items.
>
> Referenced from: /Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb/index.js
> Referenced from: /Users/me/Documents/my-project/.eslintrc.json
>     at validateRuleOptions (/Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:113:15)
>     at Object.keys.forEach.id (/Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:153:9)
>     at Array.forEach (native)
>     at validateRules (/Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:152:30)
>     at Object.validate (/Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-validator.js:230:5)
>     at loadFromDisk (/Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:549:19)
>     at load (/Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:592:20)
>     at configExtends.reduceRight (/Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:421:36)
>     at Array.reduceRight (native)
>     at applyExtends (/Users/me/Documents/my-project/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:403:28)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update babel-preset-react and eslint-plugin-react, that solved the problem for me.
If that raise new errors, you will be forced to update almost everything related to eslint.

Comment: The project which created by `create-react-app` doesn't use `eslint-config-react`. It uses `eslint-config-react-app` which seems has dependency issues with latest `eslint` and `babel-eslint`. Any solution for this?